# Is a pure coherent sheaf locally pure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $F$ be a pure coherent sheaf of $O_X$-modules, that is any non-zero subsheaf $E\subset F$ satisfies $dim(E)=dim(F)$ (by dimension of a sheaf, I mean the dimension of its support).

It is known that a $F$ is pure if and only if all its associated points have the same dimension (the dimension of $F$). A proof can be found in Alain Leytem thesis (https://orbilu.uni.lu/handle/10993/23380), Theorem 3.1.11.
I understand the proof in the local case, but I'm wondering how to go from the global to the local case. More precisely:

*Is a sheaf $F$ pure if and only if $F|_U$ is pure for all affine subset $U\subset X$ ?*

The ***if*** part is clear. Now, assume $F$ is pure. If it admits a subsheaf $K\subset F|_U$ on some affine open $U\subset X$, is it possible to extend $K$ to a subsheaf $K^{'}\subset F$ on the whole scheme $X$ ? Maybe a better way to proceed is to say that the generic point $\eta$ of $Supp(K)$ is associated to $F|_U$, and therefore $\eta$ is also associated to $F$. Then one needs to show how to associate a subsheaf of $F$ to an associated point of $F$.

Comment: Yes, you can extend $K$. The exact statement is: let $F$ be a coherent module on a Noetherian scheme $X=U \cup V$ with $U,V$ nonempty open subschemes and $V$ affine, and $K \subset F_{|U}$ be a submodule. Then it extends to some coherent submodule $K’ \subset F$. The proof is as follows: it is enough to consider the extension from $U \cap V$ to $V$ (and then glue), so we can assume $X$ affine, $V=X$. Then $K’$ is determined by its global sections. We define those to be $K(U)$: it all works out – after some work – because $U$ is separated quasicompact so $K(D(f))=K(U)_f$ if $D(f) \subset U$.

Comment: @Mindlack thank you for your comment. The only point i'm not sure about, is how to defined an injective map $K(U)\to F(X)$ (seeing $K(U)=K^{'}(X)$ as a $A$-module, for $X=Spec(A)$). Say $U=D(f)$, as elements of $K(U)\subset F(U)$ are classes of fractions $\dfrac{m}{f^k}$ with $m\in F(X)$, must we chose a representative class $\frac{m}{f^k}$ with $f$ not a divisor of $m$, so that the map $K(U)\to F(X), \dfrac{m}{f^k}\mapsto m$ is well defined ?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I completely forgot that part – in many settings there will indeed not be an injective map $K(U) \rightarrow F(X)$. Here’s how it actually works: $K’(X)$ will be $\{m \in F(X),\, m_{|U} \in K(U)\}$. Then $K’_{|U}$ is contained in $K_{|U}$ (consider what happens at principal open subsets contained in $U$). But if $V=D(f) \subset U$ and $t \in K(V)$, $t=s/f^q=v/f^q$ for some $q \geq 0$, $v \in K(U)$ (because Noetherian) and $s \in F(X)$, so that for some $r \geq 0$, $(s_{|U}-v)f^r=0$, and $t=(f^rs)/(f^{q+r})$ with $f^rs \in K’(X)$ so that $t \in K’(V)$.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. In fact in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022789/finitely-generated-submodule-of-a-localisation they essentially prove the same thing. Thank you for your help, if you want you can rewrite your comments as an answer and I can accept it. Thank you ! :)